# Passing UIViewController by reference or get self control in another handler class

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have created a seperate class **MyUtil** for handling some basic operation like navigation right left button and their events. LeftButton(UIBarButton left) is handled but right is displayed but not handled.

Please suggest me another way round.

**MyUtil.h**

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface 

    @interface MyUtil : NSObject

    @property(strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *uiv;

    -(void)NavAndBackBtn:(UIViewController *)context;// it is running awesome.

    -(void)NavAndForwardBtn:(UIViewController *)context :(NSString *)vc_name;//it displays right button but don't know how to add pushViewController to it in this class. 
//context is self of calling ViewController and vc_name is the name of ViewController which i want to push

    @end
```

**MyUtil.m**

```
#import "MyUtil.h"
#import "ForgotPassViewController.h"

@implementation MyUtil


-(void)pushingView:(UIViewController *)vvc  secondInput:(NSString *)view_name
{
    Class theClass = NSClassFromString(view_name);

    id myObject = [[theClass alloc] init];

    [vvc.navigationController pushViewController:myObject animated:YES];
}

-(void)method:(NSArray *)val
{

}
-(void)NavAndBackBtn:(UIViewController *)context

{
    UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [button addTarget:context.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 20)];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    context.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =barButton;
}

-(void)myMethode:(NSArray*)params
{

    UIViewController *vvc = [params objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *strArg = [params objectAtIndex:1];

    Class theClass = NSClassFromString(strArg);

    id myObject = [[theClass alloc] init];

    [vvc.navigationController pushViewController:myObject animated:YES];
}

-(void)NavAndForwardBtn:(UIViewController *)context :(NSString *)vc_name
{
    UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setTitle:@"Skip" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 20)];

    //[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   // NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:context,vc_name,nil];

    [button addTarget:self.leftDelegate action:@selector(context)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   // [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethode:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 // [button add]
    //[button performSelector:@selector(myMethode:) withObject:params afterDelay:15.0];


    /// doctory...
//    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
//                                [context methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(changeImage:)]];
//    
//    [invocation setTarget:context];
//    
//    [invocation setSelector:@selector(changeImage:)];
//    
//    [invocation setArgument:(__bridge void *)(context) atIndex:2];
//   
//    [invocation setArgument:(__bridge void *)(vc_name) atIndex:3];
//    
//    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f invocation:invocation repeats:NO];




    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    context.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =barButton;

}

-(void) pushNewVC: (UIViewController *) vvc : (NSString *) str
{

    NSString *strArg = str; //[NSString stringWithFormat:string];

    Class theClass = NSClassFromString(strArg);

    id myObject = [[theClass alloc] init];

    [vvc.navigationController pushViewController:myObject animated:YES];

}
```

@end

I have been trying it for two days but didn't find a way to get self in another class by reference . some says it is not possible to pass by reference but it does whatever you want . I sent self to MyUtil.m class it displays right and left UINavigationItem.leftButton and RightButton.

**LeftButton in MyUtil**

```
 [leftbutton addTarget:context.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //it is doing absolutely what i wanted..
```

Now for rightbutton to open(Push ViewController) i did

[rightbutton addTarget:context.navigationController action:@selector(pushViewController:animated:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// how can i pass a UIViewController to open. how above function knows what to open

I have tried multiple ways to solve this issue 
**First method to pass multiple params in selector;**
 myMethode:(NSArray *)params

**Problem 1**

Is it possible to send self as &self. and get it in another class .I tried it and in MyUtil.h . I also use ** double pointer but it is not passing.

**Problem 2**
Is it possible to multiple parameter in my case they are UIViewController and NSString or both be UIViewController

**Problem 3**

Is there a way to send or attach UIViewController to given statement

**Problem 4**

I have created a  `@property(strong,nonatomic)UIViewController *vc;`

when i assign  `self of calling ViewController` to vc . it is not working as i expected. is there a way to get self of another ViewController to be be handled and capture in a property of that class.

```
[button addTarget:context.navigationController action:@selector(pushViewController:animated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

//how can i told this function to push which ViewController because i am having two UIViewController in function.

**Note** 
I am working in another class name MyUtil. Main problem is i am unable to call `[self.navigationController pushViewController:anyVC]` out of a function in MyUtils.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but why don't you create a **Category on UIViewController** to handle what you want to do ? What your MyUtil is doing sounds like a category to me and in that case you have access to self for your UIViewController.